# How to add a sand finish texture to cement skimcoat

Tags: concrete, finish

I am building a house in the Philippines.  It is cement block construction ant the interior walls have been skim coated smooth. Not painted.
What I am trying to accomplish now is to apply a "sand finish" texture to one wall, to be painted as an "accent wall".
Not many product choices are available here so I'm looking for suggestions on how I can achieve the desired outcome.

Is it possible to mix sand into the cement skimcoat and apply with a rubber or sponge float to obtain the finish I'm looking for?
Need suggestions please.

Comment: It can be done with the sand that is already present in the cement, if it could be skimmed again. Otherwise, perhaps add sand in the paint?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing with my block retaining walls.  You are right on track with your idea to skim coat and use a sponge float.  You can use any cement mixture without aggregate - either a sand mix or a mortar/stucco mix.

The procedure is pretty simple.  Apply the skim coat and trowel it relatively smooth.  Wait until it starts to set (I usually waited 15-20 minutes but I was outside - your temperature/humidity will determine) and then float with a wet sponge float.

Answer (score 0):

Mix a thin batch of your drywall mud or plaster, whatever you are using. Add sand - make sure the sand grit size is uniform and not too large or fine.

Using a paint roller, apply the thin sandy mud onto the wall. Make sure you test a small area first.

To make swirl patterns: use a brush to create overlapping swirl strokes on the mud before it dries. (see a tutorial here: https://drywall101.com/articles/texturegroups/swirl.php)

If working on an exterior concrete wall, I'd imagine you could use a paint roller to apply a thin layer of sandy concrete in the same manner.